# How to set cell value?

Tags: java, poi-hssf, hssfworkbook

I have got the following code:

```
        HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        Cell resultCell=(Cell) sheet.getRow(1).getCell(0);
```

Problem is result cell doesn't have any method setCellValue(). Following statement gives me an error

```
 resultCell.setCellValue("PASS");
```

Comment: [Cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue%28double%29) very much has a `setCellValue` method! Whyever would you think it didn't?

Comment: @Gagravarr No it doesn't. Check it in an IDE. HSSFCell has a setcellvalue method

Comment: I did, and it very much does! You must have imported the wrong class

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Apache POI JavaDocs for Cell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html), or [the Apache POI Cell examples on the website](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#CreateCells), you will clearly see that `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell` has a number of `setCellValue` methods including [setCellValue(double)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue%28double%29) and [setCellValue(String)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell.html#setCellValue%28java.lang.String%29)

Most likely you've imported the wrong class for `Cell`. You should review the `import` statements at the top of your class, remove the wrong ones, and ensure you only have one of:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Worbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
```

or:

```
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
```

Answer (score -1):

The correct code is this one
 HSSFCell resultCell= sheet.getRow(1).getCell(0);
I were not supposed to caste the cell object